# non www url is redirecting to homepage

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have `.htaccess` settings to get any non-www request to www.

It works for the home page, but when I check other URLs it goes to the home page.

Here are my settings (**UPDATED**): Top part is coming from laravel

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


</IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    
    RewriteEngine on
    
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
    
    #First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
    
    #Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
    RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
    </IfModule>
```

For example

`https://example.com` goes to `https://www.example.com`.

But `https://example.com/contact` doesn't go to `https://www.example.com/contact`. Instead, it goes to `https://www.example.com`.

What can be the problem and solution?

Comment: How are you routing requests for `/contact`? (Or what does a request for `/contact` map to?) It looks like you have some directives missing from your config?

Comment: I have edited by putting the part that ı have at the top. may be more clear now.

Comment: On the other side i have this redirection created automaticly on cpanel. https://i.imgur.com/60YyZlB.png

Comment: Yes, your directives are in the wrong order, as already explained in my answer. That cPanel redirect is already included in the directives you posted. (That's all cPanel does for you - it edits the `.htaccess` file, but the redirects it adds are always at the end of the file - which is usually the wrong place.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but `https://example.com/contact` doesn't go to `https://www.example.com/contact`

Assuming you are not simply using extensionless URLs (ie. `/contact` maps to `/contact.php`) with MultiViews/mod_negotiation then you must have other mod_rewrite directives that route these requests.

It looks like you may have put these directives in the wrong order.

The external redirects in your question need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` *before* any internal rewrites to a front-controller.

*Aside:*

> ```
> #First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

This rule should be redirecting to `https://`, not `http://`. Otherwise you are going to get multiple, unnecessary redirects (https to http and back to https).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
> RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
> ```

This rule (currently last), needs to go at the top. Generally, any blocking directives should be first. You can also simplify/optimise this a bit...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

`L` is implied when using `F`. If there is no *substitution* string then you should use `-`, not `?`.

---

**UPDATE:** Following your updated question, my initial answer/hypothesis is confirmed... your directives are in the wrong order. Your external redirects need to go *before* the Laravel front-controller.

Otherwise, in its current order, a request of the form `example.com/contact` is first internally rewritten to `index.php` by the Laravel front-controller and then there will be an external redirect to the canonical scheme + hostname, so the net result is you are redirected to the homepage.

The cPanel redirect you mentioned in comments simply manifests itself as a rule in `.htaccess` (which you've already included). But note that all cPanel redirects are placed (often incorrectly) at the end of the `.htaccess` file (this is [stated in the cPanel docs](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/redirects/)).

So, in summary, your directives should be written like this:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    
RewriteEngine on

#
# BLOCKING DIRECTIVES
#

# Block certain requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

#
# CANONICAL REDIRECTS
#
    
# Redirect non-www to www + HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
    
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
    
#
# Laravel directives follow...
#

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

ıt seems that is working with this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        
    ## Force https and www
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

</IfModule>
```

Any extra suggestions to optimize are accepted with pleasure

Comment: I had already explained the "wrong order" of directives in my answer. You basically just needed to reverse the two blocks, and put **all* your external redirects first (which I stated in my answer). In your updated directives, the two redirects at the end should still go at the top, otherwise they won't do what they are supposed to do. Please see my updated answer that includes a summary of the directives in the correct order.